# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.model_selection'; 'sklearn' is not a package

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been dealing with this much too long. I am using a MacBook Pro. This suddenly started happening when running Jupyter. I could not fix it.  I completely uninstalled anaconda (which was using Python3.8) then completely uninstalled Python3.9. I installed Python3.96.  Then went back to basics and reinstalled numpy, pandas, sklearn.  Everything seems to be there in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages

This command fails in IDLE and gives the error in the title of my question.

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

It does not give the error in Mac's Terminal

The search path for IDLE looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip to install it.

And it's called scikit-learn instead of sklearn in pip, if you are using Jupyter, do

```
!pip install scikit-learn
```

If you already have it, try

```
!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Comment: Tried it.  It installed a few extras but I got the same response: 'sklearn is not a package'. Since it works from Terminal but not from Idle, I think the problem lies with Idle - but what??

Comment: What's your filename, if your filename is something like sklearn.py which could cause this problem. If you can installed it from terminal and not idle, that's because idle is just a pythonn repl. If filename is not the case, use pip3 install of pip. Since Mac came with a python2, that might cause some problem.  !pip3 install scikit-learn

Comment: I use pip3 install. I also ran a small sklearn script in terminal.  The same script in IDLE fails with the error message "No module named 'sklearn.model_selection'; 'sklearn' is not a package"  But it is clearly a package in my IDLE search path.

Comment: Yes, it's called scikit-learn. You will need to use pip install scikit-learn to install it. And aparts from IDLE, you can try to use some other IDEs like Pycharm or Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few weeks of simply using Googles Colab I did the following.  Purchased App Cleaner and Uninstaller for Mac and got rid of all Python related apps that I do not need any more after moving to Colab and Kaggle's API.  Removed and reinstalled Python.  Ran the Idle program again and it worked!  Yay!.  The problem started while using Jupiter with Anaconda.  Just randomly appeared.  When I decided to work on it again yesterday I thought it might have been some malware on my Mac.  The reason I thought it was malware is that the Idle message was giving me the message that sklearn was not a package and it could not find train_test split - even when I asked for another sklearn module - e.g. datasets.  It always referred to train_test_split even when I did not request it.  Hence the cleanup of my Mac (everything Python related and more).  It's all good now.